# Foregin keys returns empty results

Tags: mysql

I'm using an a mySQL db on localhosts. Created table with primary key and another table with foreign key pointing to that one, but when I want to see the results all I geted is "alert" that MySQL returned emty result. Here my tables

```
CREATE TABLE example_1(
    ex1_id int  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(50)  NULL,
    last_name varchar(50)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT example_1_pk PRIMARY KEY (ex1_id)
);

CREATE TABLE example_2 (
    ex2_id int  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    acces_lvl int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT example_2_pk PRIMARY KEY (ex2_id)
);

CREATE TABLE example_3 (
    ex3_id int  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first int  NOT NULL,
    second int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT example_3_pk PRIMARY KEY (ex3_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (first) REFERENCES example_1(ex1_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (second) REFERENCES example_2(ex2_id)
);
```

Then I add something to db, eg.

```
INSERT INTO `example_1`(`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `example_2`(`acces_lvl`) VALUES (2)
```

then when I try

```
SELECT * FROM `example_3`
```

I have nothing, empty results. Shouldn't be there id's from other tables? Am I doing something wrong, or I didn't do something? I'm totally noob in database.

Comment: You didn't use `INSERT INTO` for `example_3`. How should there be an result if you didn't add anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did not insert any data into example_3.  Foreign key constraints don't propagate data, they just enforce the data relationship, so when you do insert data into example_3, the values you put in the columns with foreign key constraints have corresponding values in other table.

Comment: Yes I forgoted, hoever, when I added something to example_2 column I got NULL in both first and second column (changed 'first' and 'second' in example_3 that they can be null)